# Exposing a Collection to a VB6 app through COM Interop

Tags: vb.net, com, vb6, com-interop

I am trying to add the following function to my COM Class Library and it will not compile. I believe you can't expose Collections to COM. I thought by using RegAsm and registering Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll as a tlb on both my VS2013 machine and VB6 machine it would work but it doesn't.

If not then what would be the best way to pass some sort of object list to a VB6 app.

```
    Public Function GetCustomerCollection() As Collection
    Dim collection As New Collection

    Dim c1 As New customer
    c1.Name = "Test Customer1"
    c1.Phone = "(888) 777-9443"
    c1.Balance = 22.58

    Dim c2 As New customer
    c2 .Name = "Test Customer2"
    c2 .Phone = "(888) 433-4423"
    c2 .Balance = 99.99

    collection.Add(c1)
    collection.Add(c2)

    Return collection
End Function
```

**UPDATE**
**In VB6 I am trying this to retrieve the list:**

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim demo As New testLibrary.Demo

Dim customerList As Collection
Set customerList = demo.GetCustomerCollection

Label1.Caption = customerList(1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection class is not `<ComVisible(True)>`.  Any of the .NET 1.x interfaces and collection classes in System.Collections are good.

The COM way is to only expose interfaces, so use IEnumerable if the VB6 code should not modify the collection, IList if it does.  So you want to write it like this:

```
Public Function GetCustomerCollection() As System.Collections.IEnumerable
    Dim collection As New List(Of customer)

    collection.Add(New customer With {.Name = "Test Customer1", .Phone = "(888) 777-9443", .Balance = 22.58})
    collection.Add(New customer With {.Name = "Test Customer2", .Phone = "(888) 433-4423", .Balance = 99.99})

    Return collection
End Function
```

And substitute IList if modification is desired.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent response, any chance you can take a look at my update above and tell me what I am doing wrong in my VB6 code trying to retrieve the collection?

Comment: You are still using the Collection class, don't do that.

Comment: How do I retrieve it then? using CreateObject?

Comment: An example on how I would retrieve the first customer in my VB6 app would be great if possible.

Comment: I would think you just use this to retrieve the name of the first customer `Dim objColl As Object: Set objColl = GetCustomerCollection: Debug.Print "First customer name is " & objColl(0).Name ` NB the first customer will be item zero